# Can I bring a lightsaber from Disneyland into Australia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, airport-security, disney

I want to visit Galaxy's Edge and build myself a custom lightsaber, as well as maybe buy a couple of the legacy ones for display in my theatre room. If I have them packed with the blades removed, can I expect any issues with customs at the Australian border? (I don't want to lose a lot of money and regret the experience.)

Comment: Um... lightsaber _blades?_

Comment: @MikeHarris Cheap translucent plastic tubes that lights up when you turn on the toy., I assume.

Comment: Just tell the customs agent, clearly and calmly, "these are not the lightsabers you're looking for".

Comment: @ugoren Don't try that if the customs agents are [Toydarians](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Toydarian#Biology).

Comment: My son bought a lightsabre at Disney World and there was the option to send it by UPS (or Fedex, can't recall) to the UK from the shop. This worked fine and avoided any issues with TSA, airline or Customs as it went the the 'fast parcel' system.

Comment: Not sure about Australia, but TSA in the USA allows it: https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/light-saber